# FStream read txt file

Tags: c++, fstream

I tried many solutions, nothing works, absolute and relative paths. I changed directories as well, etc. My code always worked this way, and I got no clue what can be wrong.

Two examples of what I did:

```
// Read a file into memory
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

int main () {
    std::ifstream is ("test.txt", std::ifstream::binary);
    if (is) {
        // Get length of file:
        is.seekg (0, is.end);
        int length = is.tellg();
        is.seekg (0, is.beg);

        char * buffer = new char [length];

        std::cout << "Reading " << length << " characters... ";

        // Read data as a block:
        is.read (buffer,length);

        if (is)
           std::cout << "all characters read successfully.";
        else
           std::cout << "error: only " << is.gcount() << " could be read";
        is.close();

        // ...buffer contains the entire file...
        std::cout << buffer;
        system("PAUSE");
        delete[] buffer;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
char pfad[256]; //The path to the application is stored here.
_getcwd( pfad, 256);
std::string truepfad;
truepfad = pfad;
truepfad.append("\\test.txt");
fstream f("C:\\Users\\Etix\\Documents\\test.txt");
string s;
if (!f)
    std::cout << truepfad;
else
{
    std::cout << "open file";
    while (getline(f, s)){
        std::cout << s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors I get while using your code are:

```
 Error: Expected a declaration.

 Error: This declaration has no storage class or type specifier.
```

I think the problem might be that your missing some #include's. I saw you need #include 
<string> and several others as well as an improperly made if statement at line 44 
(with the #include <string>).

Comment: NEVER use using namespace std;
Biggest beginner mistake you can do in C++.

the error was due to a misconfig of my windows, the code is fine, i dunno why you get this errors, but you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Personally I think it's alright to do it with smaller projects, but I agree that for bigger projects using namespace std; will be bad.